# Changing eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have some symmetric matrix $A\in \mathbb{N}^{n\times n}$. By already done calculations we know that $A$ has some eigenvalues say $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n$ (since $A$ is symmetric we know we have a full set of eigenvalues).

Consider the following term where $I$ is the identity matrix.
\begin{align}
Z=(A-\lambda_iI)
\end{align}

My question is: What is achieved by this term concerning eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: What means *to kill eigenvalue?*

Comment: I meant kill eigenvector as i already somehow edited in the title. (such that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ but not of $A-\lambda I$.)

Comment: $Z$ ill of course have new eigenvalue(s)... $0$ at least! Moreover if $2\lambda_3$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$, $\lambda_3$ will still be an eigenvalue of $Z$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net "Kill" means "set equal to zero", apparently

Comment: @Felix Note that $A - \lambda_3 I$ and $A$ have exactly the same eigenvectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $Z$ are exactly $0$, $\lambda_1 - \lambda_3$ and $\lambda_2-\lambda_3$. The eigenspaces associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i - \lambda_3$ is exactly the eigenspace of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.